# Javascript, Validar correctamente mi Formulario, usando Select y File

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nodejs, reactjs

me ayudan a entender y ver la forma correcta de validación de un formulario con Javascript.
Estuve realizando varias formas de validar, seguí muchos tutorial, simple y avanzado donde estuve viendo  var,let,const, expresiones, =>, pero no comprendí al 100% claro, es por que no tengo buena base en Javascript, lo cual tengo que buscar un buen curso para aprender.
Ahora, me podrían ayudar a corregir las validaciones, la única que toma hasta el momento es el primer input "tabla_reg". Me gustaría validar el select y file, los demás no son obligatorios solo validar los caracteres.
Lo hice de muchas formas, pero quede con esta, y quedo estancando en en el select y file. ¿Cuál sería una buena forma para validar mi formulario?. Si no es mucha la molestia, como se hace para que aparezca el código ejecutable en stackOverflow?. Se los agradecería mucho, gracias por su tiempo :)

```
// Validaremos los campos INPUT 
function validarInput() {
    // Variable que usaremos para determinar si el input es Valido.
    let isValid = false;

    // Los Inputs
    const input = document.forms['guardar_evento']['tabla_reg'];
    const select = document.forms['guardar_evento']['select_responsabilidad'];

    // Mensaje de error
    const message = document.getElementById('formulario__input-error');

    input.willValidate = false;
    select.willValidate = false;

    // expresion
    const val_input = new RegExp('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{0,8}$/');
    const val_select = document.getElementById('select_responsabilidad').innerHTML = "";

    // Validacion Servicio
    if (!val_input.test(input.value)) {
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        isValid = true;
    }

    if (!val_select.test(select.value)) {
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        isValid = true;
    }
}

 //  función que verificar validación
 function verificar() {
    const valido = validarInput();
    if (!valido) {
      alert('No Se Permiten ·$"%&/(&/¨^*Ç¨.', input);
    } else {
      alert('Formulario Correcto y listo para guardar.');
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<!-- Save Evento-->
            <form action="{% url 'save_evento' interno=bus.interno %}"  id="guardar_evento" method="post"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="container ">
                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center transparent_background_detalle_interno">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <!-- Grupo: Tabla -->
                                    <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__tabla">
                                        <label for="tabla_reg" class="formulario__label">TABLA</label>
                                        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
                                            <input type="tel" class="formulario__input" id="tabla_reg"
                                                placeholder="Ingrese el Servicio" minlength="3" maxlength="8"
                                                name="tabla_reg" value="{{tabla_ret}}">
                                            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="formulario__input-error">No Se Aceptan, *^¨Ç¨"$%$/)/·</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <!-- Grupo: Código -->
                                    <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__codigo">
                                        <label for="cod_operador" class="formulario__label">CÓDIGO OB </label>
                                        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
                                            <input type="tel" class="formulario__input" id="cod_operador"
                                                placeholder="Ingrese el Código" minlength="1" maxlength="4"
                                                name="cod_operador" value="{{codigo_ret}}">
                                            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="formulario__input-error">No Se Aceptan, *^¨Ç¨"$%$/)/·</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- Grupo: Código -->
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas">RESPONSABILIDAD</h3>
                                    <select class="bg-warning form-control form-control" id="select_responsabilidad"
                                        name="responsabilidad" >
                                        <option value="0" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "" %}selected{% endif %} disabled>
                                            Seleccione Una Responsabilidad
                                        </option>

                                        <option value="O" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "O" %}selected{% endif %}>
                                            Operaciones
                                        </option>

                                        <option value="V" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "V" %}selected{% endif %}>
                                            Vandalismo
                                        </option>

                                        <option value="M" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "M" %}selected{% endif %}>
                                            Mantenimiento
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <div class="col-md-5 m-3 p-3 rounded-lg rgba-stylish-strong" id="graffiti_section"
                            style="display: none;">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input class="custom-control-input" id="graffiti" type="checkbox" name="graffiti">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="graffiti">Tiene graffiti?</label>
                            </div>
                        </div> -->

                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas">LINEA DE RECORRIDO</h3>
                                    <input type="text" class="border rounded border-primary form-control"
                                        id="tabla_linea" placeholder="Ingrese el Recorrido" minlength="3" maxlength="10"
                                        name="tabla_linea" value="{{linea_ret}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row mt-4">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas">OBSERVACIÓN</h3>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="observacion" id="observacion"
                                        value="{{observacion_ret}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container p-3">
                    <h4 class="evento_detalle_title mt-2 mb-2">TOMAR FOTO</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="file" id="foto1" name="foto1"
                                accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif;capture=camera" class="input-foto"
                                onchange="detectFile(this, 1)" value="{{foto1_ret}}" required>
                            <label id="input_foto1" class="border rounded col-12 label-foto" for="foto1">
                                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro icon_base" id="icon_upload1"></i> Foto 1
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="file" id="foto2" name="foto2"
                                accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif;capture=camera" class="input-foto"
                                onchange="detectFile(this, 2)">
                            <label id="input_foto2" class="border rounded col-12 label-foto" for="foto2">
                                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro icon_base" id="icon_upload2"></i> Foto 2
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="file" id="foto3" name="foto3"
                                accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif;capture=camera" class="input-foto"
                                onchange="detectFile(this, 3)">
                            <label id="input_foto3" class="border rounded col-12 label-foto" for="foto3">
                                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro icon_base" id="icon_upload3"></i> Foto 3
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="container p-1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 btn_flota mb-1">
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-block" href="{% url 'buscar_interno' %}">Buscar otro interno</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 btn_flota mb-3">
                            <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="validarEvento();" type="submit" value="Guardar" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="formulario__mensaje" id="formulario__mensaje">
                            <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> <b>Error:</b> Por favor rellena el formulario
                                correctamente. </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el código un código que yo utilizo para validar un modal, hay que capturar varios selects y un campo de texto, cualquier elemento que dejes sin añadir o capturar algo te notifica e impide que puedas presionar el botón de aceptar.  Lo edite un poco para no colocar todo el código, nada mas lo que te podría servir.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    function validaFormAsignacion(){
         // Selectores
           var Asignacion = $("#Asignacion<?= $a+1?>").val();
             //alert("El valor del Tipo de  Asignacion es "+Asignacion);
           var Estado = $("#Estado<?= $a+1?>").val();
             //alert("El valor de Estado del  Bien es "+Estado);
           var Ubicacion = $("#Ubicacion<?= $a+1?>").val();
             //alert("El valor de Ubicacion del bien es "+Ubicacion);
        if($("#tipoAsignacion<?= $a+1?>").val() === "0"){
        swal("Indique el tipo de Asignaci\u00F3n por favor.","Haga clic en OK para Cerrar","error");
        $("#Asignacion<?= $a+1?>").focus();  
        return false;
        }
        if($("#estadoAsignacion<?= $a+1?>").val() === "0"){
        swal("Seleccione un estado del Bien por favor.","Haga clic en OK para Cerrar","error");
        $("#estadoAsignacion<?= $a+1?>").focus();
        return false;
        }
        if($("#Ubicacion<?= $a+1?>").val() === "0"){
        swal("Indique la Ubicaci\u00F3n del Bien por favor.","Haga clic en OK para Cerrar","error");
        $("#Ubicacion<?= $a+1?>").focus();
        return false;
        }
        if($("#Observaciones<?= $a+1?>").val() === ""){
        swal("El campo Observaciones no puede estar vacío.","Haga clic en OK para Cerrar","error");
        $("#Observaciones<?= $a+1?>").focus();   
        return false;
         }

    return true; // Si todo está correcto
    }
     hace una peticion ajax 
     recarga los selects
     etc...


}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, lo revisare, me gusto lo del *SLAW*, en ves de Alert, esta super.

Comment: @JorgeToro Si revisa y adaptalo a tus necesidades y haciendo test es la única manera de comprobar que realmente funciona y hace lo que necesitas.  Para la alerta swal utilice la versión original, ya van en swal2 , sweet o algo asi,  igual puedes checar cual te conviene mas utilizar.

Comment: Si me sirvió, Muchas Gracias, te pasaste :) @Cesarin

Comment: @JorgeToro  Un gusto que te haya servido!!  Saludos.